# Rest Service Access inside fragment class

Tags: android, rest, listview, android-fragments

In my application i need to display the data in list view from rest service . I have gone through many samples but am not satisfied with that so can somebody help me ?  Need sample or explanation . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In android you can use libraries to consuming REST

- [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Your question is very general. Try one from above.

Sample use Volley:

in gradle: `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
 String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
}
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
 queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I am new to android development can u please tell me how to use these lib

Answer (score 0):

you can call api in fragments.

if you are new to android,
 1)first fetch the data from api with a asynctask(check android json parsing with url in learn2crack).

2)after step 1 you have your data to populate to your list,if you want to make a custom list the same site also gives an example for android custom list(learn2crack)

you can call json  on asynctask class.
call the async task in onCrateView of your fragment